# Is stat or stati64 buggy in windows?

Tags: c, windows, perl, winapi, kernel

I am seeing a strange problem in my project where perl could not see a file though it is present in the disk.  We run a series of short backend jobs ( each spanning 10 s ) through perl. The backend job write an output file and exit, later which perl process would try to transfer it. The job runs fine initially and all of a sudden fail to detect file written by the backend. Debugging perl code ( 5.10.1 from http://www.cpan.org/src/ ), I found stati64 ( win32_stat in win32.c ) fail and return -1. On retry, the call seem to work fine. I can guarantee there there is no race condition involved by backend process as we try to access the file in perl only after backend exit.

Does anyone know conditions (when used recursively in short jobs) under which stat ( or stati64 ) can say file absent though file exist in windows? Does it cache the result of previous execution for optimization?

Comment: Try switching your virus scanner off.

Answer (score 1):

If you can reproduce the problem, use [SysInternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (or the deprecated but easier-to-use Filemon) to see what's going on.

One possible cause is that some other application (such as an antivirus program or indexing engine) has locked the file, but Procmon should show the error code from `stat`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried procmon and captured the events for file activity This show that stat operation on file succeed - CreateFile, QueryInformationVolume, QueryAllInformationFile, CloseFile ( for stati64 ). But the return value from the call is -1 and GetLastError() show 6. Before the file "test_31.01.dat" is checked, we check the existence of "test_31.01.dat.lock" for which filemon showed as unsuccessful. This is okay as the file doesn't exist in the code context. There are no external agents like virus scanner, index engine interrupting here. Could there be any optimization issue?

Comment: With procmon, are you filtering on the filename (rather than the process name)?  You want to be sure to detect any other concurrent access.  Also, how consistent is the problem?  If there is variation in when and which file, it would seem more likely to be a race condition than an optimization issue.

Comment: Yes, it is based on filename. out of 300 runs on same file, i would get between 1-100 for sure. I doubt if there is a race condition since  procmon clearly show the status has succeeded. I am surprised why return value just come as -1 and extended error as 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out why you get an error, you should check the error message. It is found in `$!`, and maybe more precisely in `$^E`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a very similar issue under different circumstances. When attempting to access a file via CGI, `_stati64()` would return -1 with an errno of ENOENT "No such file or directory". I wrote a simple C program to run `_stati64()` on the file to see if the results were the same and it worked correctly.

Further investigating with Procmon showed that the process being called via CGI would fail on the `CreateFile` operation on the parent directory of the file in question; the result was always ACCESS DENIED which is the same result as trying to access a file that does not actually exist.

The fix ended up being the following

- making a copy of the original parent directory and all contents
- deleting the original
- renaming the copy to the original name

Yeah, I have no idea what caused this but it was a very frustrating issue to debug. My guess is that the CGI access was failing due to botched permissions in the original directory.